# Javascript ByteBuffer to base64 string not Returning image

Tags: javascript, html, protocol-buffers, intel-xdk, protobuf.js

Making a HTML5 app in Intel XDK, so computation is done in Javascript.

Case: getting a (google) protobuf message from server. Parse that to object. We have an image in there, jpg. Gonne put that into the HTML. Hey, you can use base64 for that... Have done this in Android; there you can use BitmapFactory:

```
Bitmap bitmap = android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(document.getDocBlob().newInput());
```

After some google-fu found stuff like this:

```
var base64String = btoa(String.fromCharCode.apply(null, new Uint8Array(currentComment.Document.doc_blob.buffer)));

var ByteBuffer = ProtoBuf.ByteBuffer;
var base64String = ByteBuffer.btoa(currentComment.Document.doc_blob.buffer, currentComment.Document.doc_blob.littleEndian, currentComment.Document.doc_blob.noAssert);
```

**Here is the snag:** the image does not show up: it shows broken link image. But no errors are thrown when the above first function is used. Where I think I go wrong is with offset. The data structure looks like this:

```
buffer: ArrayBuffer
  byteLength: 148199
  __proto__: ArrayBuffer
limit: 69895
littleEndian: true
markedOffset: -1
noAssert: false
offset: 44278
view: DataView
```

The setting to the HTML is done like so, and it works, have tested it with other base64 strings:

```
commentImage = document.getElementById("img-frame"); 
var source = "data:image/" + image_type + ";base64," + base64String;

commentImage.setAttribute("height", currentComment.Document.doc_height);
commentImage.setAttribute("width", currentComment.Document.doc_width);
commentImage.setAttribute("src", source);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how we made it work: the blob was the whole blob with a point where the image started and where it should end.

Option A: normal btoa() - faster

```
var base64StringA =  btoa(String.fromCharCode.apply(null, new Uint8Array(currentComment.Document.doc_blob.buffer.slice(currentComment.Document.doc_blob.offset,currentComment.Document.doc_blob.limit))));
```

Option B: Bytebuffer.btoa() - slightly slower (but I think this is a safer option due to not being dependant how the btoa() is defined in the window, that one is dependant on the browser used...)

```
var base64StringB = ByteBuffer.btoa(String.fromCharCode.apply(null, new Uint8Array(currentComment.Document.doc_blob.buffer.slice(currentComment.Document.doc_blob.offset, currentComment.Document.doc_blob.limit))), currentComment.Document.doc_blob.littleEndian, currentComment.Document.doc_blob.noAssert);
```